# MATLAB search path error

Tags: linux, matlab

This is something that's baffling to me.  I have the Control Systems toolbox and when I try to use the `ss` function, I get the following error:

> The class 'ss' contains a parse error or cannot be found on MATLAB's search path, possibly
>   shadowed by another file with the same name.

When I perform `help ss` in the Command Prompt, it seems to pull up the help page for the `ss` command.  Do you have any ideas? I don't have any other files that are named `ss`.

Is there any way to specify the use of `ss` from the Control Systems toolbox.  This is quite bizarre, and I don't think I have seen this before. I tried to search for this but all the results seemed to be about MATLAB Object-Oriented Programming.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is the result I get when I use `help ss` in the Command Prompt:

> `ss`  Construct state-space model or convert model to state space.
>
> Construction: `SYS = ss(A,B,C,D)`creates an object `SYS` representing the continuous-
>        time state-space model
>
> ```
> ....
> ....
> ```

Comment: Do you have a variable with the same name as `ss` in your workspace?  Try doing `clear ss` then try the command again.  The message (unfortunately) doesn't tell you about variables having the same name in your workspace as well.  This can also shadow over the state space function.

Comment: I don't think so...I ran the same script with the same data on my laptop and I had no issue. It's really intense so I moved it to a linux desktop and that's when I started having issues. Ill double check on the variable name though. Thanks

Comment: Try `which ss -all` and see if it finds anything it shouldn't.  Other things to check: Does the same error occur if you try one of the simple examples with `ss` from the help file?  Does `ver control` give you the same result on both laptop and desktop systems?

Comment: This is not a solution, but a check: What happens if you put a copy of ss (with the same name!) in your current directory and then try to use the command?

Comment: i did a clear ss and the issue is still there so its not a variable interfering with the function. here are the results from `which ss -all`
`/usr/local/mathworks_r2013b/toolbox/control/control/@ss/ss.m             % ss constructor
/usr/local/mathworks_r2013b/toolbox/control/control/@DynamicSystem/ss.m  % DynamicSystem method
/usr/local/mathworks_r2013b/toolbox/ident/ident/@idParametric/ss.m       % idParametric method
/usr/local/mathworks_r2013b/toolbox/signal/signal/@dfilt/ss.m            % dfilt method`

Comment: i copied ss to another folder and opened matlab and cd into that dir. i do which ss -all and the folder shows up in the list. i do one of the examples in the help ss doc `sys = ss(zeros(1,1,2))` and here is the result `Error using ss
The specified superclass 'numlti' contains a parse error or cannot be found on MATLAB's search path,
possibly shadowed by another file with the same name.`

Comment: this mystery deepens...we have multiple versions of matlab installed on this linux box. same issue on matlab2011b, but the problem goes away on matlab2009b! what in the world is going on!?!

Answer (score 0):

so thanks to all the suggestions for troubleshooting i was able to figure out what was wrong. apparently the sys admin who did the matlab installation had a modified pathdef that was screwing up the search path for the toolboxes. when i cleared the matlab path's and went with the default matlab search path all my issues went away. thank you guys so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Matlab R2013a). I was trying to call `ss` from my own `classdef` class. I received this error:

```
Error using ss
The class 'ss' contains a parse error or cannot be
found on MATLAB's search path, possibly shadowed by
another file with the same name.
```

The problem was that my own class was called `StateSpaceModel`, and `ss` has following definition:

```
classdef ss < numlti & StateSpaceModel
```

So, when I was inside the default Matlab path, `ss` inherited the correct Matlab class called `StateSpaceModel`. But when I was inside my folder, `ss` was trying to inherit my own class with the same name.